# Usage of mixed and scalar product vectors

Tags: vectors

I'm writing a project and I am stuck on the last part which I have to explain the usage of mixed and scalar product of vectors, where are they useful, what could be done with them in the future and so on. Where can I find information about this?

Comment: What level of class is this?

Comment: The class is called "Mathermatics 1". I'm not sure about level, I'm in college and it's my first year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a lot things with the scalar product and the mixed product, but they're two really different things:

The scalar product, roughly speaking, measures the angle between two vectors in space, whereas the cross product produces a normal vector for two vectors, mean one that is being orthogonal to both of them. The mixed product is then a mix between them, taking three vectors into account. They're a lot of application of either in many fields, physics, for example.

I would like to refer you to the [Wikipedia article on triple product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product) and on the [dot product.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).

Hope that helped you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helps a lot. Do you mind if you write some of the "many" things I can do with them, so I can research more in-deep?

Comment: Let me refer to this page: http://www.nabla.hr/Z_MemoHU-020.htm and don't mind to mark my post as an answer ;-)

Comment: Interesting article. Thanks a lot!